# Restart Eclipse application

Tags: eclipse, plugins

How can I restart an application in Eclipse through a socket call?
I built an error diagnosis app which can checks what code should be changed to handle the error, but after the change I have to restart the app again. I already have developed a plugin for Eclipse which would take care of this, but I am not sure on how to restart the app.

1.) Is there an internal Eclipse command to restart the app?

2.) Do I have to use a command shell (which I wouldn't prefer)?

Hope someone can help me or give me some guidance. Also I know that there is a possibility to restart an app for debugging, but I want to run the app without debugging.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean you have an Eclipse 3.x style RCP application and you want to restart the RCP from an Eclipse plug-in then you just do:

```java
PlatformUI.getWorkbench().restart(true);
```

which restarts the RCP using the current workspace.

For an e4 RCP you do:

```java
@Inject
IWorkbench workbench;


workbench.restart();
```

Answer (score 0):

@greg-449: Thanks for your respond, but what I am trying to achieve is a bit more complex. Consider the following, I have a service that runs on another machine in my company network. It turned out something wrong is going with this service. So you can connect with with a remote debugger to the server and can check with the source code, that you have on your local machine, what is going on. I would say the classic Remote Debugging in Java.

But when you have fixed the error in the code you also have to restart the service on this other machine somewhere in the network. The question is how to do this? By a shell command which gives you the instances on this machine where the service is running or is there some other possibility?

Hope this helps more to understand the problem.